# no such item for cursor instance

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

This is the code I used to retrieve data from two different collections and matched them on the department criteria. However after running the function for 7 times, I get an index Error of "no such item for cursor instance"

````
def update_instructor_course(college,department,department_course_list):
    get_department_courses = (courses.find({"college": college, "department": department}))
    get_department_instructors = (employees.find({"college":college, "department": department}))[:len(department_course_list)]

    for index, instructor in enumerate(get_department_instructors):
        employees.update_one({"_id": ObjectId(instructor["_id"])},{"$set": {"course": [get_department_courses[index]['course_code']]}})
        courses.update_one({"_id":ObjectId(get_department_courses[index]["_id"])}, {"$set":{"instructor":instructor['employee_id']}})```
````

Comment: Please post full traceback. Are you sure there should be data and no other processes have modified it between your requests?

Answer (score 0):

The find method always returns an instance of the **cursor**, in order to work with it as a list, you need to use the **to_list(...)** method, which accepts the number of elements to form the list or None.

```
get_department_courses = courses.find({"college": college, "department": department}).to_list(None)
```